# Getting the tops of side-by-side widgets to align using PySide

Tags: python, layout, pyside

In the code below, the top of the `QTextEdit` and `QGraphicsView` widgets are not aligned when using `QHBoxLayout`. However, if you comment out `QTextEdit` and uncomment the other `QGraphicsView` setup, the top of the widgets align perfectly. Here are my questions:

1. What causes this alignment issue to occur and how can it be fixed?
2. Are issues like this best avoided by using Qt Creator?
3. Is the whole QGraphicsView() --> QGraphicsScene() --> QWidget() necessary to place graphics next to other widgets?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        # Create Widget1
        widget1 = QTextEdit()
        #widget1 = QWidget()
        #view1 = QGraphicsView()
        #scene1 = QGraphicsScene(0,0,200,500)
        #view1.setScene(scene1)
        #layout = QHBoxLayout()
        #layout.addWidget(view1)
        #widget1.setLayout(layout)


        # Create Widget2
        widget2 = QWidget()
        view2 = QGraphicsView()
        scene2 = QGraphicsScene(0,0,200,500)
        view2.setScene(scene2)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(view2)
        widget2.setLayout(layout)


        # Layout of Side by Side windows
        container = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget1)
        layout.addWidget(widget2)
        container.setLayout(layout)

        # Scroll Area Properties
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        scroll.setWidget(container)

        # Scroll Area Layer add
        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Widget()
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layouts have a default margin. So if one widget is in a layout, and its neighbour is not, they will not be aligned. To remove the default margin, you can do this:

```
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

However, in your example, the container widget and layout for the `QGraphicsView` aren't doing anything useful. So you could remove those, and along with some other simplifications, arrive at this:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        widget1 = QTextEdit()
        widget2 = QGraphicsView()
        widget2.setScene(QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 200, 500, widget2))

        container = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(container)
        layout.addWidget(widget1)
        layout.addWidget(widget2)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        scroll.setWidget(container)

        vLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vLayout.addWidget(scroll)
```

Using Qt Designer is certainly very useful when experimenting with the layouts of a complex application. However, the code it generates is usually quite verbose compared with what you can achieve when coding by hand. For long-term maintainability, though, using Qt Designer seems the best option.

Comment: Thank you. Clear & concise.